# I install Android Studio but its shows some error install build tool 21.1.1 please suggest me

Tags: android

I install Android Studio but its shows some error install build tool 21.1.1 please suggest me

also I cant find build tool folder in `c/user/<>/appdata/local/buildtool/...`

please suggest me

Answer (score 0):

Launch SDK Manager from within Android Studio and download build tools.

Answer (score 0):

Try reinstalling the Android studio using the short guide i provided below.. If the problem persist after the installation , Consult the Google Android Studio Known issues page ..

Follow the underlying steps for an installation from scratch ..

- Download the Android studio bundle from the following links for the operating system you are using now

  [For Windows](https://dl.google.com/dl/android/studio/install/1.0.1/android-studio-bundle-135.1641136.exe)

  [Mac osx](https://dl.google.com/dl/android/studio/install/1.0.1/android-studio-ide-1641136.dmg)

  [Linux](https://dl.google.com/dl/android/studio/ide-zips/1.0.1/android-studio-ide-135.1641136-linux.zip)
- Install the Android studio in your computer
- Download the JDK for the system (X86 (32bit) or X64(64bit)) [ Depends on your system architecture.. Mine is 64 bit OS, So i downloaded the 64 bit Android Studio bundle and Jdk ]
- If you are using Windows , Go to your My computer properties , Click **advanced system settings**   then open the Environment Variables by clicking the button , Then click the New button located below the System variables .. Add a variable named **JAVA_HOME** and the JDK path as the variable value ..

[image: Screenshot of my settings]

- For Mac osx Android Studio Installation, Consult this Lynda Tutorial on the following link [Click here](http://www.lynda.com/Android-tutorials/Installing-Android-Studio-Mac-OS-X/143103/168103-4.html)
- Restart your system ..